# Is there anyway to find how many prime factors has a composite number without knowing them?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

Let's call f(n) the function that gives us the number of different prime factors of a composite number n
For example: f(24)=2

Let's call g(n) the function that gives us the number of prime factors of a composite number n
For example: g(24)=4

Does g or f exist?

Comment: It exists since you just defined it. Want are you looking for?Is it a polynomial? No.

Comment: It exists, you just cannot find it without factoring the number. However, see  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erd%C5%91s%E2%80%93Kac_theorem

Comment: The question of the title is interesting. I interpret it as asking whether there is an algorithm for computing the number of prime factors that is (significantly) faster than  known "good" factorization algorithms. For primality there is.

Comment: @AndréNicolas I know that there are a lot of algorithms for computing the prime factors, but I never found one that just gives us the number of factors without calculating them first. That's why I think that this a mathematical question therefore requires a theoretical answer. And I think that the Erdős–Kac theorem referred by Will Jagy is very close to the answer but deals with probability and would like a more "solid" way to find the number of factors.